# discord.js don't return anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        // Set a new item in the Collection with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNiNG] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property`)
        }   
    }
}

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    
    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interacftion.commandName} was found`);
        return;
    }

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemral: true});
        } else {
            await interaction.reply({content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral:true})
        }
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

i ran that code but it doesn't work and terminal didn't return anything.
i don't know why it doesn't return anything such as an error.

```
PS C:\Users\NURIE\OneDrive\.myspace\coding> cd web/discord-bot
PS C:\Users\NURIE\OneDrive\.myspace\coding\web\discord-bot> node index.js
```

i tried to run it, but it doesn't work because of something. The problem is that the code doesn't work. i hope to solve this problem as soon as possible

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing Events.InteractionCreate you should be doing "interactionCreate" and the reason why it's not returning any output when executing it, is because you are not logging anything. To have it log something at start use the event "ready" and log something in there.

Comment: super thanks to you